# how to mute a application in flutter

Tags: flutter

i need help to disable sound in my app when the user toggles the mute switchlistitle.

```
SimpleDialogOption(
          child: SwitchListTile(
              title: Text('Mute'),
              secondary: Icon(Icons.volume_mute),
              value: _mute,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  _mute = value;
                });
              }),
        ),
```

Comment: by mute you means? what exactly do you want ?

Comment: i don't know how set volume to 0 in one press of a switch

Answer (score 0):

First intialise your value where at first you want mute or not.

```
bool _mute;
    @override
      void initState() {
    //you decide what you want here
    _nute=false;
    }
```

then change value according to that. You have to fix this logic `_mute = !value`.

```
SimpleDialogOption( child: SwitchListTile( title: Text('Mute'), secondary: Icon(Icons.volume_mute), value: _mute, onChanged: (bool value) { setState(() { _mute = !value; });}))
```

Comment: i want to disable sound in app. I don't know how to disable sound in the app

Comment: i'm asking what function must i use to disable audio in app

Answer (score 0):

The mute switch works in the app.

```
late bool mute;

 Switch(
          value: mute,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              mute = !mute;
              (mute == true) 
               ? player.setVolume(0) 
               : player.setVolume(1);          
            });
            print(mute);
          }),
```